# Timestampadd with current timestamp as default value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to **add + 1 day to the current timestamp** when a new entry is inserted into a table. While I would normally just do it in PHP by adding the time before inserting, I want to try to just use MySQL and set that timestamp as the **default** value.
I've tried to do the following:

```
TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

[image]

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) COMMENT 'Timestamp request token time',
  ' at line 8
SQL Code:

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `new_db`.`reset_tokens`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_db`.`reset_tokens` (
  `reset_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Reset ID',
  `users_user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK User ID',
  `user_reset_token` CHAR(30) NULL COMMENT 'Reset character string (30)',
  `user_ts_expiration` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) COMMENT 'Timestamp request token time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`reset_id`, `users_user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_reset_token_UNIQUE` (`user_reset_token` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_reset_tokens_users1_idx` (`users_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reset_tokens_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `new_db`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Reset tokens / forget password'
```

I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't work, but maybe this is just the wrong way to do it. Any/better alternatives are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

So I checked the "Target MySQL version" and it said "8.0.16" (engine InnoDB). The thing is, changing it to for example 10.1.34 creates a whole set of new issues.

**EDIT 2**
I changed the version to 10.1.34 and resolved some issues but regarding the `TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, it still gave the same error (doesn't make a difference when I try `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`).

Let me be clear, I'm not trying to `SELECT`, I want to set it as a `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: Could you please post the whole mysql query not just a snippet

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Prior to MySQL version 8.0.13, you could not provide **expressions** as a Default value for datatypes. Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Also current timestamp is a function, try adding () to the end "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your MariaDB version does not yet support using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value and/or using functions as defaults.  From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default-column-option):

> MariaDB starting with 10.0.1
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP may also be used as the default value for a DATETIME
>
> From MariaDB 10.2.1 you can use most functions in DEFAULT.

You would need to be running MariaDB version 10.2.1 or later in order for your default logic to work.

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using MariaDB? I see no mention of that.

Comment: Um...the error message in the OP clearly says `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version`.

Comment: I can confirm this information is right. And if you are using MySQL, I don't know which is the starting supporting version, but 5.7.26 also fails to handle that query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());` this works no problem for me.

As far as I can tell you just forgot to add () to the end of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I also added a select to the beginning because you didn't provide a whole query so I just went with the simplest complete query I could think of.

If that still doesn't work then I recommend you do as the error suggests and check your version of MariaDB to see if those functions are supported.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` without parentheses should be acceptable as a default (assuming the OP's version of MariaDB supports it).`

Comment: True, it's hard to tell without version details as well as the rest of the query.